# Receiving WM_COPYDATA in Python

Tags: python, windows, winapi, ctypes, pywin32

I am trying to read from Python the `WM_COPYDATA` message some applications (I'm trying with Spotify) send to WindowsLiveMessenger to update the "What I'm listening to..." phrase.

From what I have been able to find, `WM_COPYDATA` messages come in a `COPYDATASTRUCT` with the following structure:

- `dwData` in our case 0x547 so that it access the listening now feature
- `cbData` with the length of the string received
- `lpData` with a pointer to the string itself, may include Unicode characters

The string should have the following format: `\0Music\0status\0format\0song\0artist\0album\0` as stated by [ListeningNowTracker](http://listeningnowtracker.googlecode.com/svn-history/r8/trunk/ListeningNowTracker/README.TXT)

What we receive in a `WM_COPYDATA` event is a pointer for `lParam` that contains the `COPYDATASTRUCT`.

I started tinkering with pywin32 functions and I remembered that they do not accept Unicode characters from past experience, then I switched to ctypes. Despite this being an almost new world in Python for me, I tried with `POINTER()` and all I got was unknown objects for me or access violations.

I think that the code should create a `COPYDATASTRUCT`:

```
class CopyDataStruct(Structure):
    _fields_ = [('dwData', c_int),
                ('cbData', c_int),
                ('lpData', c_void_p)]
```

Then make the `lParam` be a pointer to that structure, get the string pointer from `lpData` and finally get the string with `ctypes.string_at(lpData,cbData)`.

Any tips?

**UPDATE 1**

The `WM_COPYDATA` event is received by a hidden window built with `win32gui` just for this purpose. The copydata event is connected to a function called `OnCopyData` and this is its header:
`def OnCopyData(self, hwnd, msg, wparam, lparam):`
The values the function delivers are correct as compared with the ones from the Spy++ messages log.

**UPDATE 2**

This should be close to what I want, but gives a NULL pointer error.

```
class CopyDataStruct(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [('dwData', c_int),
                ('cbData', c_int),
                ('lpData', c_wchar_p)]

PCOPYDATASTRUCT = ctypes.POINTER(CopyDataStruct)
pCDS = ctypes.cast(lparam,  PCOPYDATASTRUCT)
print ctypes.wstring_at(pCDS.contents.lpData)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I wrote the following trivial win32gui app:

```
import win32con, win32api, win32gui, ctypes, ctypes.wintypes

class COPYDATASTRUCT(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('dwData', ctypes.wintypes.LPARAM),
        ('cbData', ctypes.wintypes.DWORD),
        ('lpData', ctypes.c_void_p)
    ]
PCOPYDATASTRUCT = ctypes.POINTER(COPYDATASTRUCT)

class Listener:

    def __init__(self):
        message_map = {
            win32con.WM_COPYDATA: self.OnCopyData
        }
        wc = win32gui.WNDCLASS()
        wc.lpfnWndProc = message_map
        wc.lpszClassName = 'MyWindowClass'
        hinst = wc.hInstance = win32api.GetModuleHandle(None)
        classAtom = win32gui.RegisterClass(wc)
        self.hwnd = win32gui.CreateWindow (
            classAtom,
            "win32gui test",
            0,
            0, 
            0,
            win32con.CW_USEDEFAULT, 
            win32con.CW_USEDEFAULT,
            0, 
            0,
            hinst, 
            None
        )
        print self.hwnd

    def OnCopyData(self, hwnd, msg, wparam, lparam):
        print hwnd
        print msg
        print wparam
        print lparam
        pCDS = ctypes.cast(lparam, PCOPYDATASTRUCT)
        print pCDS.contents.dwData
        print pCDS.contents.cbData
        print ctypes.wstring_at(pCDS.contents.lpData)
        return 1

l = Listener()
win32gui.PumpMessages()
```

I then sent the window a `WM_COPYDATA` message from another app (written in Delphi):

```
Text := 'greetings!';
CopyData.cbData := (Length(Text)+1)*StringElementSize(Text);
CopyData.lpData := PWideChar(Text);
SendMessage(hwnd, WM_COPYDATA, Handle, NativeInt(@CopyData));
```

The output was:

```
461584
461584
74
658190
2620592
42
22
greetings!
```

So it seems that it works trivially, pretty much as you coded it.

The only thing that I can think of is that the text in Spotify's `COPYDATASTRUCT` is not null-terminated. You should be able to check that quite easily by reading out the data. Make use of the `cbData` member.

Comment: @Chiva Any feedback? Is this useful to you?

Comment: It works! But it is almost exactly the same code as the one I have written... maybe other code breaks it.  Although it is not critical for me, it gives me an `UnicodeEncodeError` when receiving [songs titles with greek characters](http://open.spotify.com/track/4qamMrvmDXHSLBbdPpGu7P), putting the utf-8 encoding line doesn't fix it. Sorry for the delay, but I have been busy all day.

Comment: @Chiva try and look at the binary representation of the string that breaks and we should be able to work out how it has been encoded.

Comment: How I am supossed to get the binary representation?

Comment: You're update is really a new question. I already answered your question. It's not fair to keep changing the question! You should now accept this answer (I believe I answered your original question) and then ask a new question.

Comment: OK, done. Just found the bug I had and learned a lesson, don't call events by hand. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Could you have a look at a very similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13291818/python-win32gui-automation-send-wm-copydata-to-get-data-from-bsplayer