# Receiving a Windows message in Python - UnicodeEncodeError ...?

Tags: python, character-encoding, sendmessage

I have a little Python 3.3 script that successfully sends (SendMessage) a WM_COPYDATA message (inspired from [here](http://nullege.com/codes/show/src@i@p@ipython-py3k-HEAD@IPython@deathrow@scitedirector.py/26/win32con.WM_COPYDATA/python) , works with [XYplorer](http://www.xyplorer.com/index.php)):

```
import win32api
import win32gui
import struct
import array

def sendScript(window, message):
    CopyDataStruct = "IIP"
    dwData = 0x00400001                           #value required by XYplorer
    buffer = array.array("u", message)
    cds = struct.pack(CopyDataStruct, dwData, buffer.buffer_info()[1] * 2 + 1, buffer.buffer_info()[0])
    win32api.SendMessage(window, 0x004A, 0, cds)  #0x004A is the WM_COPYDATA id

message = "helloworld"    
sendScript(window, message)                       #I write manually the hwnd during debug
```

Now I need to write a receiver script, still in Python. The script in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5249903/receiving-wm-copydata-in-python) seems to work (after correcting all the `print` statements in a `print()` form). *Seems* because it prints out all properties of the received message (`hwnd`, `wparam`, `lparam`, etc) **except** the content of the message.
I get an error instead, **UnicodeEncodeError**. More specifically,

```
Python WNDPROC handler failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\xxx.py", line 45, in OnCopyData
    print(ctypes.wstring_at(pCDS.contents.lpData))
  File "C:\Python\python-3.3.2\lib\encodings\cp850.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_map)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 10-13: character maps to <undefined>
```

I don't know how to fix it, also because I'm not using "fancy" characters in the message so I really can't see why I get this error. I also tried setting a different length of message in `print(ctypes.wstring_at(pCDS.contents.lpData))` as well as using simply `string_at`, but without success (in the latter case I obtain a binary string).

Answer (score 0):

`ctypes.wstring` (in the line `print (ctypes.wstring_at(pCDS.contents.lpData))`) may not be the string type that the sender sent. Try changing it to:

```
print (ctypes.string_at(pCDS.contents.lpData))
```