# IPC Equivalent of ObjectiveC postNotification and addObserver in Win32API

Tags: objective-c, winapi, ipc

I am coming from a bit of Mac background. I am trying to do some simple IPC.

I am making a script for an application which always scripts to run ctypes during runtime. Thus I am able to use the C libs like Objective-C and Win32API.

This application which I am writing script for has two individual processes. Users of my script run it in both instances as a "hook"/"module" so to speak. It is not an injection, it is ctypes-like run during run time. Pretty cool.

I need to send a string from Process 1 to Process 2. In Mac I accomplished this feat by running the script from Process 2 which set up an observer for a notification with name `blahBlahBlah`. I did this in Objective-C ctypes by running the script of `addObserver:selector:name:object` in Process 2. Then in Process 1 I sent the string by running script `postNotification:notificationName:object:userInfo:deliverImmediatey`.

Is there such a way in Win32API?

I read this example here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649009%28v=vs.85%29.aspx and thought to make a hidden window win WinAPI and set up that code but I can only run code during runtime so this may not be possible.

Comment: See [Interprocess Communcation on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365574%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  Sounds like a pipe or a mailslot might be suitable.

Comment: Thank you @HarryJohnston, are mailslots async? Or just the pipes?

Comment: According to what I've read, you can use both pipes and mailslots in either synchronous or overlapped mode.  I haven't had any reason to use mailslots so I can't speak from my own experience.